# Access a POST value from View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to access a POST value from the View (without passing by the controller)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @Html.TextBox("SomeValue")    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
}

The value being posted is @SomeValue
```

What is the right syntax for **@SomeValue**

Comment: Think about what your asking here. How exactly would you get this information to the view without the controller doing the rendering?

Comment: In PHP5/Symfony, this is possible, and very useful. I don't know if it is possible in ASP.NET MVC!!

Comment: At the very least you could use the view bag collection to stuff the value across to the view.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here? You want to avoid a post-back completly? You just want to remain on the same page but grab the form data and render it under the form? This is very unclear.

Comment: No I don't wanna avoid a postback, I just wanna show the user what he **posted** without passing by the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the forms collection could be accessed by:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

...but why? It defeats the purpose of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to something client-side, you should be using JavaScript and not put logic in the view. Views should be dumb.

Replacing the line:

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeValue")
```

With

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeValue", new {Id = "somevalue"})
```

Would allow you to access the value once the view has been rendered with JQuery like so:

```
$("#somevalue").val()
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is the Value of the TextBox, before it goes to controller, you can get it via javascript.

Change your HTML to have a Span so that we can change the content of it later

The value being posted is

Override your submit behavior and get it

```
<script type="Text/javascript">
  $(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $("#spanVal").html($("#YourTextBoxID").val());
        });
  });

</script>
```

This wont really submit the form to the `HTTPPOST` action method of the controller but shows the value in the textbox inside the span.